# User identification through certficate on Java glassfish SSL server

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, glassfish

I have a WSDL WebService running on Glassfish v4 and want to identify a user. Every user has a password protected private key (.pfx format).

The problem is, that I cannot read the certificate on my server.

Client code:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "/path/to/user_privatekey.pfx");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "thepassword");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "PKCS12");

System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/to/cacerts.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");
```

Server code:

```
@WebService(serviceName="MyService")
public class MyService {

    private WebServiceContext wsContext;
    @Resource
    private void setWSContext(WebServiceContext wsCtx) {
        this.wsContext = wsCtx;
    }


    @WebMethod(operationName = "test")
    public String test(){
        if (this.wsContext != null) {
            MessageContext msgCtx = this.wsContext.getMessageContext();
            HttpServletRequest httpSR = (HttpServletRequest)msgCtx.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST );
            X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[])httpSR.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

            if (null != certs && certs.length > 0) {
                System.out.println(certs[0].toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("cert is null/empty");
            }

        }

        return "test";

    }

}
```

I have added the public key of the user (.crt) to the cacerts.jks/truststore of my Server and also added the server certificate to the truststore of the client.

But `certs` is always `null`. I am sure, that the user certificate is sent, because if I don't send it or remove it from the server's truststore, I get an exception.

Comment: Have you restarted the server after you added the user cert to the truststore?

Comment: Yes, I have tried restarting, but same results